# Populate ComboBox with Enum in Delphi with MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, enums

I have an Enum **TRole**

```
type
  TRole = (Admin, Common);
```

In my database (MySQL), I have a table **users** with a column **role** of type **INTEGER**. I want to populate a ComboBox with the Roles in the following way:
The ComboBox should display "Administrator" in the role `Admin` and "Common User" in the role `Common`; when I save the value to the database, it should be save as 0 for the `Admin` role or 1 for the `Common` Role (their respective indexes).

Also, when displaying the role field, it should be displayed as the Strings showed above.

Can anyone please explain me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used two different approaches to solve this problem. One is to use RTTI to derive the name from the enum, but that would not work in your case, so here is my other method, which is more brute force:

(You can adapt to your use - note my actual functions are from classes, but that is not important)

```
function EnumAsText(
  const pEnum: TRole): string;
const
  cResults : array[ TRole ] of string =
  (
     {Admin}            'Admintrator',
     {Common}           'Common User'
  );
begin
  Result := cResults[ pEnum ];
end;
```

Then fill the drop down with something Like

```
procedure FillComboBox( Const pComboBox : TComboBox )
var
  iRole : TRole;
begin
  pComboBox.Items.Clear;
  for iRole := low( TRole ) to Hi(TRole) do
  begin
    pComboBox.Items.Add( EnumAsText( iRole ) );
  end;
end;
```

The advantage of use the const array in EnumToText as opposed to a case statement (the obvious way to do it) is that if you extend the enum, the compiler will force you to modify the function accordingly.
The ItemIndex of the combo box corresponds to your integer field.

Comment: Almost there... the problem is that it need to be saved as **INTEGER** in the database. Your way works if I wanted to save them as Strings

Comment: Not if, as I said, you use the ItemIndex property of the combo box, which is an integer and corresponds exactly to your field.

Comment: So, in this case, I wouldn't use a TDBComboBox to save this field, but a common TComboBox and save manually by the ItemIndex?

Comment: Ah, yes, I would indeed do that. You would need to save as strings to use TDBComboBox. To be honest I tend not to use data aware controls - I find them too restrictive. OK, you have to do your own database handling but that is the price to pay for flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need TRole enums for this at all. Simply populate ComboBox with entries so that their index corresponds to database values (0 = Administrator; 1 = Common User). Also set Style property of ComboBox to csDropDownList.

```
procedure PopulateComboBox(const cb: TComboBox);
begin
  cb.Clear;
  cb.Items.Add('Administrator'); // ItemIndex = 0
  cb.Items.Add('Common User'); // ItemIndex = 1
end;
```

Now when you get your data with SQL request you apply value of **Role** column directly to ItemIndex property of combobox:

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'select Name, Role from table where ID = :ID';
...
if Query.FieldByName('Role').AsInteger in [0..1] then
  RoleComboBox.ItemIndex := Query.FieldByName('Role').AsInteger
else
  raise Exception.Create('Role column value must be in range of 0..1');
```

You do pretty much the same when you're saving role to database. Use ItemIndex property as value to be saved:

```
if RoleComboBox.ItemIndex in [0..1] then
begin
  ...
  Query.SQL.Text := 'update table set Role = :Role where ID = :ID';
  Query.ParamByName('Role').AsInteger := RoleComboBox.ItemIndex;
  Query.ExecSQL;
end
else
  raise Exception.Create('Invalid role index');
```